# How to deal with an odd date returned from sql to ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a date format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn in my sql datasource

when i look at the data in SSMS it looks fine

but when i get the return value in my C# it looks like this:

```
40927,7895138889
```

but the value in the source is:

```
2011-12-29 21:52:47.427
```

I haven't seen this before, can anyone advise on what might be happening?

thanks.

edit: i am returning this value from sql server 2005 to my asp.net mvc 1.0 nerddinner tutorial site

Comment: SQL Datasource? Why did you tag your question with `asp.net-mvc` then? Did you mean `asp.net`? I guess/hope you did so I allow myself to retag your question properly. And if you really meant `asp.net-mvc`, then why on Earth are you using a SQL data source in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: What's the original DateTime value as displayed in SSMS?

Comment: How about showing the DB schema, and maybe the properties of the SQL DataSource? Also, is "," a decimal separator in your culture? If so, then that number looks like it could be a number of days, with fraction.

Comment: @Joe i believe for this one it is: 2011-12-29 21:52:47.427

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i am returning this value from sql server 2005 to my asp.net mvc 1.0 nerddinner tutorial site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are stored as numbers in SQL, x days past some starting date (I think in 1753).   Somehow, it looks like you are storing the returned date value in a float field.   Try adding your 40927 to 1/1/1753 (40,927 days past January 1, 1753) and see if you get the right value

Try this SQL command

```
select cast( cast('1/1/1900' as dateTime) as float)
```

it will return 0, indicating Jan 1, 1900 is the first date.   I suspect the field type is smalldatetime which stores dates and times of day with less precision than datetime datatype. Valid date range for this data type is from January 1, 1900 through June 6, 2079.

The number represents number of day past Jan 1, 1900.   The fractional part is the time portion.  Try this:

```
select  cast(40927.7895138889 as dateTime)
```